# What is the biggest Couchbase cluster nodes number?

Tags: nosql, bigdata, couchbase, distributed-system

any body knows what is biggest couchbase cluster has been deployed, since there are lot of info broadcast from each node, i am doubt on the scalability

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article, it covers the growth of the game 'draw something '.  They went from a 6 node cluster to a 90 node cluster in 8 weeks due to rapid growth. They also had zero downtime in adding nodes to the cluster and at week 6 were processing 3000 drawings a second.

http://www.couchbase.com/customer-stories/couchbase-helps-omgpop-scale-draw-something-50-million-users-50-days

*Edit*

Check slide 16 on this link, cluster size of 100+ for Viber

http://www.couchbase.com/presentations/couchbase-tlv-2014-couchbase-at-viber

Comment: thanks for the info. it is still under 100, any cluster in hundreds or thousands nodes?

Comment: BTW, Just find another confusion: what if we have 10 nodes online and want to add 10 new nodes, during the rebalance, replicas could be copied to new nodes via TAP, and those active ones still serving online, so all active vbucket would still located on old 10 nodes; if we switch to replicas in new nodes, it could not be strong consistency? thanks

Comment: Hi,  Draw something had around 3.3tb of data persisted, so to store this in ram they'd have needed more like 6tb of ram, that is pretty huge.  Slide 19 on this page http://www.slideshare.net/Couchbase/ccb-12-how-draw-something-grew-to-50-million-downloads-in-50-days

I don't know of any clusters in the thousands, why do you need something that big, what is your actual use case and expected load?

In regards to the rebalance consistency is maintained.  See here for specific information on it.  http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#couchbase-admin-tasks-addremove-rebalance-background

Comment: we are going to extend to thousands in future , and need to consider scalability

Comment: What exactly is your use case though? High volume website/api? Analytics?  If you tweet @tgrall he can probably give you examples of larger deployments.

Comment: do you have his mail address, since i don't have tweet account, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer this question differently than a "simple number of nodes". In your question you are talking about scalability and some "doubts" about it.... And as you can case, as Couchbase, I have no doubts about the scalability...

When people are using Couchbase, like any NoSQL solution, they have specific use case in mind for their data. And each use case have a specific data "life cycle" (volume, throughput, expiration, ...) So what do you have in mind when you are talking about scalability?

For example I have been working on a project where we have a 20 nodes cluster processing 650,000 op/s with 30% of mutation of the data. For this specific use case, no need to go bigger. You can see in other use case like Draw Something with 80/90 nodes ~50 million total users, 16 million daily users, 2 billion documents...

So instead of talking of "hypothetical" size of the cluster, I would like to understand your use case and type of deployment (available hardware/VMs) to define what will be a good topology.

Comment: thanks, what if we are in this case: currently, in ad-exchange world, we serve all the web users , say half of the world population: 4 billion, and if we have 2 billion daily users, 10 strategy for each visit, we are targeting 20,000,000 op/s; comparably it needs 600 nodes;

Comment: @user2530422 You shouldn't think in terms of a monolithic single client/server. It ignores the reality of human geo-distribution. Putting this cluster in the USA would impact 2 Billion people, increasing latency to the application simply because of distance from servers. Multinational Enterprise applications have long abandoned the client/server pattern in favor of distributed applications. Couchbase has huge customers doing well over 1M ops/s in a single cluster. To get good answers, I recommend refining the hypothetical scenario to align with proven enterprise architectural design patterns.